# How can I use Cargo to build a library as both an rlib and a dylib but with different contents?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I would like to make a project that contains:

- a library
- bindings for C
- an executable that uses the library

The directory structure, excluding temporary files and other trash:

```
.
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│   ├── c_bindings.rs // contains C bindings for library
│   ├── compression.rs
│   ├── const_data.rs
│   ├── hash.rs
│   ├── lib.rs // library
│   └── main.rs // simple executable that uses library
└── target
    └── debug
        ├── gost_stribog
        ├── libgost_stribog.rlib
```

I want `cargo build` do this:

- build Rust library (rlib) that will ignore `c_bindings.rs`
- C library (dylib) that will use `c_bindings.rs`
- executable

The debug directory should be:

```
└── target
    └── debug
        ├── gost_stribog
        ├── libgost_stribog.rlib
        ├── libgost_stribog.so
```

What should my `Cargo.toml` look like?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Opinionated answer: **don't**.

Instead, split your code into two or three separate crates:

1. The core library.
2. The C bindings for the library.
3. (Optional) The executable.

Then, move your `c_bindings.rs` to the bindings crate as just `lib.rs`. It can depend on the core library. You can also move `main.rs` into another crate that also depends on the core library.

These three crates can be in the same source code repository, but will be built with separate invocations.

[A Cargo workspace](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1525-cargo-workspace.md) may prove to be useful; in fact it's listed as an explicit reason ("An FFI crate with a sub-crate for FFI bindings").

Comment: @Flowneee the RFC states *"Workspaces can eventually get extended with `--all` flags so in a workspace root you could execute `cargo build --all` to compile all crates"*. However, until that is completed, you will need to change into each crate's directory and run `cargo build`. A tiny `Makefile` or shell script might help bridge the gap until `--all` is implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can. and here is how. 
`$PROJECT_ROOT/.cargo/config.rs`

```
[build]
rustflags = ["-C", "prefer-dynamic"]
```

remeber that you will need to distribute your application with the rust standard library as well.

```sh
$ ls $(rustc --print=sysroot)/lib                                 
libLLVM-13-rust-1.57.0-beta.so  librustc_driver-3aebdc12af579500.so  libstd-c8bc39dac3997df6.so  libtest-4d997b51b1a49b1f.so  rustlib
```

in my case it's named libstd-c8bc39dac3997df6.so, because I'm on linux, if you are on windows, it should be in the bin folder instead of the lib folder.

also, you will need a script to run the program on linux and on MacOS. on linux and on macos you dont just put the library in the same directory as you application and expect it to work, instead you have 2 options.

1. Put the libraries inside the `/usr/lib` folder and then run it.
2. make a script that:

```sh
exec LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD ./YOU_APPLICATION $@ # this last commands tells sh to get the command line arguments.
```

Just that. :)